# Writing chained mutation/modification functions for Mutable Vectors

Tags: haskell, monads

So I want to create a method that works the same way as

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import Control.Monad.ST

type DoubleVec = V.Vector Double

incrAndSwap :: DoubleVec -> Int -> Int -> Int -> DoubleVec
incrAndSwap vec i a b = runST $ do
  mvec <- V.thaw vec
  oldval <- MV.read mvec i                          -- 1
  MV.write mvec i (val + 1)                         -- 2
  MV.swap mvec a b
  V.freeze mvec
```

but being able to "condense" the two marked lines into one function, and be able to say:

```
incrAndSwap :: DoubleVec -> Int -> Int -> Int -> DoubleVec
incrAndSwap vec i a b = runST $ do
  mvec <- V.thaw vec
  incrAt mvec i
  MV.swap mvec a b
  V.freeze mvec
```

Basically, write that `incrAt i` function.

I've tried copying the type signature of `MV.write` but I haven't been able to get anything to work with the type signatures; nothing compiles.

Here is my most recent attempt

```
import Control.Monad.Primitive

type MDoubleVec s = MV.STVector s Double

incrAt :: (PrimMonad m) => MDoubleVec (PrimState m) -> Int -> m ()
incrAt mvec i = MV.write mvec i (val + 1)
  where
    val = MV.read mvec i          -- val is stuck in monad m0
```

But I don't know how to get `val` out of the monad `m0` -- which it's in, apparently, according to the compiler.  Which makes sense.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the `MV.read` inside the `m` monad, and bind its result to `val`. Basically, it is a matter of taking the two lines of the original code and moving them verbatim:

```
incrAt :: (PrimMonad m) => MDoubleVec (PrimState m) -> Int -> m ()
incrAt path i = do
    val <- MV.read path i
    MV.write path i (val + 1)
```

BTW, just for your information, the reason the type error mentions `m0` as opposed to `m` (which might be confusing at first), is that in your code there is nothing linking the monad where `val` is defined to the monad where you do `MV.read`. But the real problem is that `MV.read` is monadic so you need to bind its result to be able to use it in the also monadic `MV.write`.